# Which binaries do I need to compile from Bitcoin Core's code for running my non-routing node as an end user?

Tags: bitcoin-core, core-lightning, compiling, installation

I need **Bitcoin Core** only for running my non-routing [core-lightning](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning) node (private channels only) as an end user (not as a developer)? The lightning node is to be run on the same machine as bitcoin core.

**1.** Do I need to compile `bench_bitcoin`, `bitcoin-cli`, `bitcoin-util`, `bitcoin-tx` and `test_bitcoin` for that purpose?

**2.** I customized the compilation with `./configure --disable-wallet  --disable-tests --disable-bench`. Are there any other flags that I could pass to `configure` in order to save on CPU and storage and still maintain my lightning node functional?

**3.** Where can I read more on each of the Bitcoin Core's binary such as `bitcoin-util`
`bench_bitcoin`, `test_bitcoin`, and `bitcoin-cli`

The research I've done so far include `config -h`and https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Core_0.11_(ch_1):_Overview .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Lightning directly interacts only with `bitcoin-cli`, which in turn interacts with `bitcoind`. Those are the only two binaries you will need, indipendently of whether you compiled the binaries yourself or downloaded a release from https://bitcoincore.org/ (always double-check that you are downloading from the right place, and check the gitian signatures when possible).

As for your customizations, I would likely not compile with `--disable-wallet` as that may have some side-effects on propagation of your own transactions, and mempool, however I cannot find any confirmation of this on the [docs](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md#disable-wallet-mode) so it might also be safe.

And finally, the binaries:

- `bitcoin-util` is a simple utility to test out proof-of-work (https://www.mankier.com/1/bitcoin-util). This likely is not used for anything outside development, so feel free to ignore this one.
- `bench_bitcoin` is a benchmarking tool, used during development, to ensure there are no performance regressions from version to version.
- `test_bitcoin` is the testsuite for integration and unit tests. It is also used during development, and not much use outside.
- `bitcoin-cli` is the bitcoin command line interface, and is the way that most things talk to `bitcoind` when running, including CLN.

Comment: Thanks, I ran `./configure --disable-tests --disable-bench --enable-util-cli --with-utils=no` and it installed just `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-cli`. I just addded the mention of `bitcoin-tx` to my question - what is it used for?

Comment: I didn't know myself, but looking at the man-page (https://man.archlinux.org/man/bitcoin-tx.1.en) it sounds like a utility to create or update transactions in their hex format before submitting them to the network. It's not needed by any tool I'm aware of.